# Correct way to downgrade Samba package

Tags: 10.04, server, samba, downgrade

I am running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS and I have installed and configured Samba 3.4.7 from the repository.

What is the correct way to completely and cleanly uninstall this version so that I can install Samba 3.0.28 which I have compiled from source?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're downgrading to 3.0.28 ? That version no longer receives security fixes from upstream.

Comment: @jelmer I want to implement real-time virus scanning using samba-vscan 0.3.6b but it is not supported on versions later than Samba 3.0.28.

Comment: As a side note, samba-vscan 0.3.6c-beta5 is available for later versions of Samba, but I have not been able to get it to compile successfully with Samba 3.4.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply uninstall Samba from the software center, or from the command-line by running:

```
apt-get remove samba-common samba
```